# Using Or / And in Do While

Tags: vb.net, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create a solution where I push a button and two random numbers appear, that are divisible and leave no remainder.  Below is the following code;

```
    Dim E1 As Integer = CInt(Int((11 * Rnd()) + 1)) 'Random number between 1 and 10
    Dim E2 As Integer = CInt(Int((11 * Rnd()) + 1)) 'Random number between 1 and 10

    Do While E1 Mod 2 <> 0
        E1 = CInt(Int((11 * Rnd()) + 1))
    Loop

    Do While E1 Mod E2 <> 0 And _
             E2 <> 1 And _
             E2 <> 0 And _
             E1 <> E2
        E2 = CInt(Int((11 * Rnd()) + 1))
    Loop

    lstDivVar1.Items.Add(E1)
    lstDivVar2.Items.Add(E2)
```

The plan is to make a question that a student can answer - by being asked to divide E1 by E2.  However, I don't want E2 to have (in chronological order to the Do While statement for E2);

(1) To be a number that causes a remainder
(2) To be 1
(3) To be 0
(4) To be the same number as E1

- These are for obvious mathematical reasons to provide questions that challenge the students more.

Unfortunately, only the first logic in my Do While for E2 is being applied (E1 Mod E2 <> 0)

Any suggestions how to apply multiple conditions to a loop - it's a mickey mouse mistake I'm sure but I can't find the answer online - so please answer kindly :)

Hugh

Comment: Your teacher almost surely meant for you to find the much better algorithm, one that does not require a loop at all.  Instead of randomly trying E1 / E2 = X, invert the problem and select a random E2 and X value.  So you can directly compute E1 = X * E2.  Never a remainder, no loop necessary.

Comment: Haha thanks - that's a novel and good way of looking at it, I tried it and it works - it's useful for me to help using processing time with the loop - works well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just had your logic wrong. This should work for you.

```
Do While E1 < 4 OrElse E1 Mod 2 <> 0
    E1 = CInt(Int((11 * Rnd()) + 1))
Loop

Do While E1 Mod E2 <> 0 OrElse _
         E2 = 1 OrElse _
         E2 = 0 OrElse _
         E1 = E2
    E2 = CInt(Int((11 * Rnd()) + 1))
Loop
```

Comment: This causes a freeze on runtime - but I think this isn't connect as I want all conditions to be met - having "OR"s will permit only one condition to succeed?

Comment: @HughJanus Works fine for me. Did you add `E1 < 4 OrElse` to the first loop? Otherwise, it will get stuck in a loop if both E1 and E2 are 2. Using Ands would require all those conditions to be true which they could never be at the same time.

Comment: Ahhh thank you sorry I missed the E1 < 4 - works a treat :D